# Combination of Union and Join in apache pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have two files in hdfs containing data as follows, File1:

```
id,name,age
1,x1,15
2,x2,14
3,x3,16
```

File2:

```
id,name,grades
1,x1,A
2,x2,B
4,y1,A
5,y2,C
```

I want to produce the following output :

```
id,name,age,grades
1,x1,15,A
2,x2,14,B
3,x3,16,
4,y1,,A
5,y2,,C
```

I am using Apache pig to perform the operation, is it possible to get the above output in pig. This is kind of Union and Join both.

Answer (score 1):

As you can do unions and joins in pig this is of course possible.

Without digging into the exact syntax, I can tell you this should work (have used similar solutions in the past).

1. Suppose we have A and B.
2. Take the first two columns of A and B to be A2 and B2
3. Union A2 and B2 into M2
4. Distinct M2

Now you have your 'index' matrix, and we just need to add the extra columns.

4. Left join M2 with A and B
5. Generate the relevant columns

Thats it!

Answer (score 1):

```
A = load 'pdemo/File1' using PigStorage(',') as(id:int,name:chararray,age:chararray);   
B = load 'pdemo/File2' using PigStorage(',') as(id:int,name:chararray,grades:chararray);

lj = join A by id left outer,B by id;
rj = join A by id right outer,B by id; 

lj1 = foreach lj generate A::id as id,A::name as name,A::age as age,B::grades as grades;
rj1 = foreach rj generate B::id as id,B::name as name,A::age as age,B::grades as grades;

res = union lj1,rj1;  
FinalResult = distinct res;
```

2nd approach is better according to performance

```
A1 = foreach A generate id,name;   
B1 = foreach B generate id,name;

M2 = union A1,B1; 
M2 = distinct M2;

M2A = JOIN M2 by id left outer,A by id;
M2AB = JOIN M2A by M2::id left outer, B by id;

Res = foreach M2AB generate M2A::M2::id as id,M2A::M2::name as name,M2A::A::age as age,B::grades as grades;
```

Hope this will help!!

Comment: I would expect this to work, but one should realize that doing the distinct in the end means that the memory requirements can be significantly higher than for the solution I suggested. -- Basically you do a hidden full outer join, so I think you might as well just use that instead of a right and left join.

Comment: This is helping, I will try to automate this for any two files (having variable columns and variable common columns). If you have any thoughts on that please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

```
u1 = load 'PigDir/u1' using PigStorage(',') as (id:int,name:chararray,age:int);
u2 = load 'PigDir/u2' using PigStorage(',') as (id:int, name:chararray,grades:chararray);

uj = join u2 by id full outer,u1 by id;

uif = foreach uj generate ($0 is null ?$3:$0) as id,($1 is null ? $4 : $1) as name,$5 as age,$2 as grades;
```